# lookup onchange event is not firing in vf page with slds

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

In VF page I have a lookup and a amount field. I need to enable/disable amount field based on lookup record type.

I tried below code:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!field.FieldPath == 'ABC__c'}">           
<apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input" value="{!objExpItem[field.FieldPath]}" id="rateId">
<apex:actionSupport action="{!getRType}" event="onchange" reRender="idLineItem" onComplete="removeMsg();" status="processImg">
    <apex:param name="abcId" value="{!objExpItem[field.FieldPath]}"/>
</apex:actionSupport>
```

Event is not fireing at all. I tried using JQery, but `inputField` Id is also no reflecting to get value by Id.

Thank you! for any valuable inputs.

Comment: Which block of the code your rendering inside  "idLineItem"

Comment: It is a parent `div` of `outputpanel`.